# Upper bound on the number of hamiltonian cycles on a $n \times n $ grid graph

Tags: graphs, combinatorics, hamiltonian-path, square-grid, hamiltonian-circuit

What is the best upper bound that is known for the number of hamiltonian cycles on a $n \times n $ grid graph?

I did some searching and found that the number of hamiltonian cycles on a planar graph with $n$ vertices is $O(\sqrt[4]{30}^n)$ where $n$ is the number of vertices in the graph. For grid graphs, I just found enumerations for small $n$, but no bounds.

Comment: Perhaps this is useful: http://www.emis.de/journals/SLC/wpapers/s34erlangen.pdf.